# Custom vallidator to ban a specific wordlist

Tags: regex, angular

I need a custom validator to ban a specific list of banned words from a textarea field.
I need exactly this type of implementation, I know that it's not logically correct to let the user type part of a query but it's exactly what I need.

I tried with a regExp but it has a strange behaviour.

My RegExp

```
/(drop|update|truncate|delete|;|alter|insert)+./gi
```

my Validator

```
export function forbiddenWordsValidator(sqlRe: RegExp): ValidatorFn {
  return (control: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: any } | null => {
    const forbidden = sqlRe.test(control.value);
    return forbidden ? { forbiddenSql: { value: control.value } } : null;
  };
}
```

my formControl:

```
whereCondition: new FormControl("", [
      Validators.required,
      forbiddenWordsValidator(this.BAN_SQL_KEYWORDS)...
```

It works only in certain cases and I don't understand why does the same string works one time and doesn't work if i delete a char and rewrite it or sometimes if i type a whitespace the validator returns ok.

Comment: Try removing parentheses, `+.` and `g` => `/drop|update|truncate|delete|;|alter|insert/i`

Comment: seems to work, thanks
I'll do some tests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues here:

- The global `g` modifier leads to unexpected alternated results when used in `RegExp#test` and similar methods that move the regex index after a valid match, it must be removed
- `.` at the end requires any 1 char other than line break char, hence it must be removed.

Use

```
/drop|update|truncate|delete|;|alter|insert/i
```

Or, to match the words as whole words use

```
/\b(?:drop|update|truncate|delete|alter|insert)\b|;/i
```

This way, `insert` in `insertion` and `drop` in `dropout` won't get "caught" (=matched).

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/IZ5JkZ/1).

Answer (score -1):

it's not a great idea to give such power to the user

Comment: It is not, but i specified it, and it is needed as is